# ElevateZoom - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Magento 1.9.1 RWD

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.9.1

I just began using Magento 1.9.1 CE to build a new version of my website. After making some minor changes, I noticed that on the product view page, the image zoom and the ability to select the different product images under More Views are both not working. Here is an example of a product page displaying the behavior: http://birne.pe/vestidos-faldas/faldas/test.html

After some digging, I discovered that Magento uses the ElevateZoom plugin for this functionality. However, I can't figure out what I might have changed to cause it to break.

This is the error message that I am seeing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function app.js:1194 
ProductMediaManager.createZoom  app.js:1194 
ProductMediaManager.initZoom app.js:1256
ProductMediaManager.init    app.js:1268 
(anonymous function)    app.js:1277 
c   jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 
p.fireWith  jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 
x.extend.ready  jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 
q   jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
```

Anybody else experiencing the same issue or know how I can fix it? Or is there more information I should add to help improve the chances of receiving an answer to this question? Thank you!

Comment: We upgraded a store to 1.9.1 yesterday and are currently facing this exact issue. No changes to theme files, markup or styles yet this functionality has broken. Reverting to the rwd theme and it works so it has to be something out of date in a theme file but can't see anything different in them at all yet. Continuing to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found it was working on the product view page but not the product review page.

Check the elevate zoom script is loaded on the page. If not check your catalog.xml file (or local.xml) depending how / if you have overridden the default. Also check review.xml

Add the below to the catalog > catalog_product_view head element and if reviews are the issue you ay need to add it to the head element in review.xml > review_product_list

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</script></action>
```

(Obviously the version of elevate zoom may be different)